# python3.5 not opening a .py file

Tags: python, subprocess

Hello im having trouble opening a .py file using processes call in python 3.5.
ive have opened other files for example a text file using this method but with .py files it seems to just skip the command. Here is my code :

`import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\Edvin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Edvin\\Desktop\\test.py'])
print ("done")`

There is no error it is simply doing >>> then >>>done when test.py isnt even open. Is this even possible for python to open another python file?

the context of test.py is:

```
print("hello world")
```

reply=input("Say hello!")

Comment: What's in the `test.py`

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when `test.py` runs?

Comment: just hello world then an input so it doesnt instantly disappear

Comment: Show the contents of `test.py`.

Comment: im expecting a black window with the hello world and an input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use run instead of call, and you had a typo in your path.

```
subprocess.run(['C:\\Users\\Edvin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Edvin\\Desktop\\test.py'])
```